# Read data in OpenOffice xlsx file then convert to a list using python

Tags: python, xlsx, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Good day. I am using pandas to read a column of data in a xlsx file. I only have 1 column and it is filled with ages of people. This is my code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel('/run/media/soumi/Luna (HDD)/CF-0001/PSHS/Statistics/Module 1/SLG 3.0 Data set 3.1 DOH COVID Data Drop Case Information.xlsx') # can also index sheet by name or fetch all sheets
num = df['B2:B57001;'].tolist()

num.sort() 
print(f'\n{num}')

fdt = pd.Series(num).value_counts().sort_index().reset_index().reset_index(drop=True)
fdt.columns = ['Element', 'Frequency']
print (fdt)
```

I am expecting that it will create a frequency table for me, however, when I run this, it shows me this:

```
 python -u "/run/media/soumi/Luna (HDD)/CF-0001/Programming/Python/Stat.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/soumi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'B2:B57001;'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/soumi/Luna (HDD)/CF-0001/Programming/Python/Stat.py", line 6, in <module>
    num = df['B2:B57001;'].tolist()
  File "/home/soumi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/soumi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'B2:B57001;'
```

What should I do to fix this? Thanks in advance

Edit 1: I'd also to add that I'm using Manjaro alone and I don't use Windows so I don't have the excel app...If that helps

Comment: `df['B2:B57001;']` will basically looking for a column named `B2:B57001;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to find column named `B2:B57001;`. What you should do, IUUC:

```
num = df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```

If you want to construct frequency table from column `Age`, then you can do this:

```
frequency = pd.value_counts(df.Age).to_frame().reset_index()
```

If you just want a list of frequency, then do this:

```
freq_list = pd.value_counts(df.Age).to_frame().reset_index()['Age'].tolist()
```

Comment: I did that and it this it the output:

```
'C987903', 'C987912', 'C987916', 'C987919', 'C987926', 'C987978', 'C987985', 'C988001', 'C997320', 'C997331', 'C997341', 'C997346', 'C997366', 'C997380', 'C997383', 'C997400', 
       Element  Frequency
0      C100018          1
1      C100025          1
2      C100054          1
3      C100055          1
4      C100115          1
...        ...        ...
56995  C999926          1
56996  C999940          1
56997  C999965          1
56998  C999978          1
56999  C999994          1

[57000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Actually it still goes on and on but stackoverflow said character too long

Comment: @H2WO, can you post first few lines of our xlsx? and what's the expected output?

Comment: https://imgur.com/SBM0vNj (this is what's inside of the xlsx). I only want to use the 'Age' column and disregard the rest. This is an example of the expected output:

https://imgur.com/FizZiwG

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question. I was trying to show you how you got the key error `KeyError: 'B2:B57001;'`

Comment: Oh that's okay...anyways my expected output (not exactly the expected but it's kinda similar) is on top of your latest comment

Comment: Answer revised, please check if that solves your problem.

Comment: I tried it and this is its output:

https://imgur.com/AzYar9z

the ages reached up to 1000+ which means there is something wrong. And also I want the answers to expand and not just show the `...` at the center. Your code is almost correct I think there was just a problem with the sorting stuff? Thanks

Comment: I can't see the 1000+. Only see up to 102 rows. To see all the outputs, would be better to output the result to excel or csv. Assuming your dataframe variable name is `frequency`, then just do this for excel `frequency.to_excel('filename.xlsx')` or `frequency.to_csv('filename.csv')` for csv.